# What is the roots for the following equation

Tags: quadratics

Can someone please show me to solve the roots for the following equation

$9x^2-8x-1 < 0 $

I am getting the root as below

$(x-9)(x+1)$ then getting $x = 9 ,~x = -1$ , which is wrong.

I have solved is as follows

Multiplication should give the value $-9$

Addition should give the value $-8$

So $(x-9)(x+1)$ is satisfying the above. Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: $(x-9)(x+1) = x^2-8x-9 \neq 9x^2-8x+1$

Comment: Note that it is obvious that $x=1$ is a root, and once this is spotted the factor is $(x-1)$ and the other factor is easy to identify too.

Answer (score 1):

To find the roots of the quadratic polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ we calculate the discriminant
$$\Delta=b^2-4ac$$
and then the two roots are *($\Delta$ may be negative)*
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$$
and finally we factorize
$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$

Answer (score 1):

For [Vieta formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) to apply, you have to divide by the coefficient of the highest power. So divide by $9$ and than the product of roots should be $\frac19$ while the sum is $\frac89$...

Comment: but the method i am using works for almost all the equations with some exceptions. Even on sites they tell to do using the same method. When should we be dividing the by the number of the highest power ?

Comment: @gaurav what are the exceptions? You should always divide! Then you conquer the equations...